# Вызвать скрипт при прокрутке страницы и за несколько пикселей до div-a (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, как вызвать скрипт при прокрутке страницы и за несколько пикселей до определенного div-a (javascript). Спасибо

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) вам в помощь. Если что у элемента есть пропорции: `offsetTop`, `offsetLef`t, `offsetWidth` и `offsetHeight` :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 пример можно?

Comment: Почитайте [ask] за вас код писать не будут, что вы пытались сделать? Что не получилось? Добавьте [mre]